# Camera Shake Effect When Camera Following Player

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was working on a 3d game where the camera is continuously following the player object.
Now when a bomb hits the player object I want to play camera shake with blast particle effect.

I have coded this for camera shake:

```
public IEnumerator PlayCameraShakeAnimation(float duration, float magnitude)
{
    Vector3 originalPosition = transform.localPosition;
    float elapsedTime = 0f;

    while(elapsedTime < duration)
    {
        float x = Random.Range(-1f, 1f) * magnitude;
        float y = Random.Range(-1f, 1f) * magnitude;

        transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x, y,originalPosition.z);
        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;

        yield return null;
    }

    transform.localPosition = originalPosition;
}
```

Camera Follow is the normal script I have written to follow the player.
Because of Camera Follow script is running, camera shake effect we can't able to show in the screen.

If I turn off Camera Follow script then we can able to see clearly camera shaking otherwise not.

If I turn off Camera Follow script for a small amount of time then I am losing smoothness in following of player because the player position gets updated after the blast. So when I start back following the player, it will get a high jerk in a movement to reach a target position.

Also, the Camera is following the player in position and rotation in both fields. Now provide me some suggestions to achieve the Camera Shake effect while following the player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually quite simple:

Separate it into two GameObjects:

```
parentObject
|--Camera
```

- `parentObject` follows player.
- `Camera` does the shaking in `localPosition` → relative to `parentObject`

Result: While `parentObject` follows the player the `Camera` is automatically moved along with it. No need to turn anything on and of ;)

Comment: Okay let me try - what you have said :)